# How can I create a new excel file/Workbook in VBA without opening it automatically?

Tags: vba, excel

I created a subroutine to create a new Excel workbook based on an input string (the new file name). This is below:

```
Private Sub AddSaveAsNewWorkbook(FILE As String)

    Dim path As String
    path = FILE & ".xlsx"
    Set Wk = Workbooks.Add
    With Wk
        .SaveAs Filename:=path
    End With
End Sub
```

However, I am using this subroutine to generate over 40,000 new files.  My computer will crash if the program opens each of these files every time. Is there any way to do this and not open the Excel file automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of continually calling `Workbooks.Add()`, just call it once, and then use `wk.SaveAs` in a loop to create all the version you need: no need to keep adding a new file in excel.  Or create a template file and copy/rename it without opening it in Excel (use `FileCopy`).

Comment: If you want to stick to your code as closely as possible, then at least call `.Close` after `.SaveAs ...`. Please also clarify that not your computer crashed but Excel which is a difference!

Comment: Put your data in a database and make one Excel file that pulls the data out. Who's going to look at 40k Excel files? Or make CSV files by writing the directly using Open and Print rather than the Excel object model.

Comment: @DickKusleika it does not matter who will look into so many files, you do not know his intension over that action.

Comment: Well @lowak I disagree. Sometimes you have to answer the question they didn't ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to create **40,000** new files, then `.Add` and `.SaveAs` will slow your PC Down. And since you do not want to open it then I would recommend using ACE for this. Here is a quick example.

**(Based on VB.Net Example [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2014/07/20/creating-a-new-excel-file-and-adding-data-using-ace/))**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim FilePath As String, sFileName As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Folder to save the files
    FilePath = "C:\Temp\"
        
    For i = 1 To 40000
        sFileName = FilePath & "File - " & i & ".xlsx"
        
        With cn
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
            .Open
            
            Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
            cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
            
            '~~> Command to create the table
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Sheet1 (Sno Int, " & _
                                                   "Employee_Name VARCHAR, " & _
                                                   "Company VARCHAR, " & _
                                                   "Date_Of_joining DATE, " & _
                                                   "Stipend DECIMAL, " & _
                                                   "Stocks_Held DECIMAL)"
            '~~> Adding Data
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Sheet1 (Sno, Employee_Name, " & _
                                                  "Company,Date_Of_joining,Stipend,Stocks_Held) " & _
                                                  "values ('1', 'Siddharth Rout', 'Defining Horizons', " & _
                                                  "'20/7/2014','2000.75','0.01')"
                              
            cmd.Execute
            
            .Close
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Note**: The two cmd.CommandTexts are alternatives as emphasized by Gserg in comments below. (Thanks For getting this sorted)

Comment: This did not work me.

Comment: What did nto work? What error do you get?

Comment: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':

Could not find installable ISAM.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Apparently it's about the missing `;` before the `Extended Properties` and the missing `""` at the end.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg. Updated it. Never got to test it and after so many years, this popped up :D

Comment: @KeithSwerling: Try it now?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well, I tested it and it works (provided the reader understands that the two `cmd.CommandText`s are *alternatives*). Also would probably be cleaner to declare `sFileName` and remove the space before the `File - `.

Comment: Cannot find Sheet1

Comment: @KeithSwerling, you need to replace `Sheet1` with the relevant sheet name.

Comment: That is the part that is still not working in your code.  But I am glad to see it is getting closer.  When Sheet1 should be created in there, it is not.

Comment: @KeithSwerling: What is the sheet name?

Comment: Sheet1 would be great.

Comment: @SiddharthRout That is the error that happens when the reader does [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126513/how-can-i-create-a-new-excel-file-workbook-in-vba-without-opening-it-automatical/69499572#comment122843728_25133439) understand that the two `cmd.CommandText`s are alternatives (as written, the `create` command never executes).

Comment: Sorry I missed that comment @GSerg.

Comment: It does work now!  Great!  I wish it had worked when I first went to use it.  It is the 2nd cmd.  I thought that was some new method I had not seen before.

Comment: VB.Net Example no longer available.  Sad face.

Comment: @KeithSwerling: Will update it soon. Gimme a day